# How can I try to find why YouTube is crashing my Ubuntu 15.10 installation?

Tags: xorg, 15.10, youtube

I have a pretty fresh installation of Ubuntu 15.10. It crashes regularly when interacting with YouTube videos. A typical example is making a playing YouTube video go to fullscreen: when it becomes fullscreen the display becomes frozen and the computer becomes unusable (though other ttys are accessible). This does not happen always, but happens very often. The previous installation of Ubuntu 15.04 did not exhibit this problem on my computer.

Obviously I want to fix this, but I'm not sure how to start to investigate what is going wrong. How should I do this?

Comment: Do you have Adobe's Flash plugin installed (I suppose you use Firefox)?

Comment: @EduardoCola Hey there, thanks for your comment. Yes, I have Adobe's Flash plugin installed. Also, I use Chrome almost exclusively and it is in Chrome that I've observed the problems.

Comment: Does it happen in Firefox, too? Do you have pepper-flash (flash for Chrome/Chromium) installed? `flashplugin-installer` does not apply to Chrome.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @EduardoCola Flash is not needed for Youtube these days at all.

Comment: But, you know, if the OP has a problem without flash why not install it and see if it works? Not about being needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a youtube video to find out if you are running Flash or HTML 5 playback. Flash is often a culprit in crashes associated  with youtube and if you are running Flash it is well worth your while to switch to so-called 'HTML 5' playback:

[YouTube HTML5 Video Player](https://www.youtube.com/html5)

I see that your favoured browser Chrome is supported and long usage on my own system has shown no problems or issues at all. Hopefully this will end the crashes on your system...

Below is a screenshot showing HTML 5 player running a youtube clip on my system, it demonstrates the right click test to see if all is running well:

[image]

Mind you I suspect that HTML 5 playback is *default* for Chrome...